# Как передать массив объектов из одного компонента в другой в React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, веб-программирование, компоненты, state

Только - только начал изучать React и столкнулся с проблемой: в приложении (что-то то вроде одностраничного интернет-магазина) при выборе товаров, они складываются в массив объектов "cartItems", который мне из "App" надо передать в "Modal", чтобы отобразить список товаров перед оформлением заказа, но никак не могу понять как это сделать, буду благодарен любой помощи.
Прошу прощения за костыли и плохо читаемый код.
Код "App.jsx":

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Button from "./Components/Button/Button";
import Card from "./Components/Card/Card";
import Cart from "./Components/Cart/Cart";
import Modal from "./Components/Modal/Modal";
<script src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-web-app.js"></script>

const { getData } = require("./db/db");
const foods = getData();

const tg = window.Telegram.WebApp;


function App() {

  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);
  const [modalActive, setModalActive] = useState(false);
  


  useEffect(()=>{
    tg.ready();
  })


  const onAdd = (food) => {
    const exist = cartItems.find((x) => x.id === food.id);
    if (exist) {
      setCartItems(
        cartItems.map((x) =>
          x.id === food.id ? { ...exist, quantity: exist.quantity + 1 } : x
        )
      );
    } else {
      setCartItems([...cartItems, { ...food, quantity: 1 }]);
    }
  };

  const onRemove = (food) => {
    const exist = cartItems.find((x) => x.id === food.id);
    if (exist.quantity === 1) {
      setCartItems(cartItems.filter((x) => x.id !== food.id));
    } else {
      setCartItems(
        cartItems.map((x) =>
          x.id === food.id ? { ...exist, quantity: exist.quantity - 1 } : x
        )
      );
    }
  };



  const onCheckout = () => {
    
    let pz = '{';
    for (let i = 0; i < cartItems.length; i++ )
    {
      if (i != cartItems.length - 1)
      {
        if (cartItems[i].quantity === 1)
      {
        pz+=('\'' + cartItems[i].title + '\'' +' ' + ':' + ' ' + cartItems[i].price + '00' + ',');
      }
      if (cartItems[i].quantity != 1)
      {
        pz+=('\'' + cartItems[i].quantity + 'x' + ' ' + cartItems[i].title + '\'' + ' ' + ':' + ' ' + cartItems[i].price * cartItems[i].quantity + '00' + ',');
      }
      
      }
      else
      {
        if (cartItems[i].quantity === 1)
      {
        pz+=('\'' + cartItems[i].title + '\'' + ' ' + ':' + ' ' + cartItems[i].price + '00' + '}');
      }
      if (cartItems[i].quantity != 1)
      {
        pz+=('\'' + cartItems[i].quantity + 'x' + ' ' + cartItems[i].title + '\'' + ' ' + ':' + ' ' + cartItems[i].price * cartItems[i].quantity + '00' + '}');
      }
      }
    }
   console.log(pz.toString());
   console.log(cartItems);

   setModalActive(true);
    
    tg.MainButton.text = "Оформление";
    tg.MainButton.show();

    tg.onEvent('mainButtonClicked', function(){
      tg.sendData(pz.toString()); 
    }); 
  }
  
  return( 
  <>
    <Modal active={modalActive} setActive={setModalActive}/>
      
    <div className="shapka">
      <div className="shapka_top"></div>
    <h1 className="heading">Каталог</h1>
    <Cart cartItems={cartItems} onCheckout={onCheckout} />
    </div>
    <div className="cards__container">
      {foods.map((food) => {
      return <Card food={food} key={food.id} onAdd={onAdd} onRemove={onRemove} />
    } )}
    </div>
  </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Код "Modal.jsx":

```
 import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
 import "./Modal.css";

 const Modal = ({active, setActive, inCart}) => {
    
    return (
        <div className={active ? "modal active" : "modal"}>
                <div className="shapka_modal">
                    <h1 className="heading_modal">Ваш заказ</h1>
                </div>
                <h1>{inCart}</h1>
        </div>

    );
 };

 export default Modal;
```

Comment: [Пропсами](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html), как и `setModalActive`

Answer (score 0):

1. Можно воспользоваться [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)-ом, который позволят передвать значения от любой компоненты в любой другой, без сложностей

   - Объявляем контекст `const ItemsContext= createContext()`
   - Оборачиваем элементы, которые будут использовать этот контекст в тег `ItemsContext.Provider`
   - Объявляем значение как объект, в котором 1 поле для значения цвета и 1 метод для обновления массива `value={{items, setItems}}`
   - В любых дочерних компонентах достаём поле или метод в зависимости от того, кому что надо. Например кнопке не важно знать, какой сейчас массив, его дело - просто добавить нужный элемент, потому он использует только метод обновления массива `const {setItems} = useContext(ItemsContext)`. Самому блоку же, плевать кто и как обновлят массив, ему важно знать только нынешний массив, потому использует только поле, где значение массива `const {items} = useContext(ItemsContext)`

   ```js
   const {useState, useContext, createContext} = React;

   const ItemsContext = createContext();

   const Item = ({pushValue}) => {
     const {setItems} = useContext(ItemsContext);
     
     return (
       <button onClick={() => setItems((items) => [...items, pushValue])}>{pushValue.name}</button>
     )
   }

   const Items = () => {  
     return (
       <React.Fragment>
         <Item pushValue={{id: 1, name: 'Item 1'}} />
         <Item pushValue={{id: 2, name: 'Item 2'}} />
         <Item pushValue={{id: 3, name: 'Item 3'}} />
       </React.Fragment>
     )
   }

   const Modal = () => {  
     const {items} = useContext(ItemsContext);
     
     return (
       <div className='block'>{items.map(item => item.name)}</div>
     )
   }

   const App = () => {
     const [items, setItems] = useState([1]);
     
     return (
       <ItemsContext.Provider value={{items, setItems}}>
         <Items />
         <Modal />
       </ItemsContext.Provider>
     )
   };

   ReactDOM.render(
     <App />,
     document.getElementById('root')
   )
   ```

   ```css
   body {
     background-color: #777;
   }

   .block {
     margin-top: 8px;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div id="root"></div>

   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
   ```
2. Просто у общего родителя объявить состояние и передавать дочерним компонентам. Но так вам придётся по всей цепочке дочерних компонентов пройтись, пока не доберётесь до нужного

   ```js
   const {useState, useContext, createContext} = React;

   const Item = ({setItems, pushValue}) => {  
     return (
       <button onClick={() => setItems((items) => [...items, pushValue])}>{pushValue.name}</button>
     )
   }

   const Items = ({setItems}) => {  
     return (
       <React.Fragment>
         <Item setItems={setItems} pushValue={{id: 1, name: 'Item 1'}} />
         <Item setItems={setItems} pushValue={{id: 2, name: 'Item 2'}} />
         <Item setItems={setItems} pushValue={{id: 3, name: 'Item 3'}} />
       </React.Fragment>
     )
   }

   const Modal = ({items}) => {  
     return (
       <div className='block'>{items.map(item => item.name)}</div>
     )
   }

   const App = () => {
     const [items, setItems] = useState([1]);
     
     return (
       <React.Fragment>
         <Items setItems={setItems} />
         <Modal items={items} />
       </React.Fragment>
     )
   };

   ReactDOM.render(
     <App />,
     document.getElementById('root')
   )
   ```

   ```css
   body {
     background-color: #777;
   }

   .block {
     margin-top: 8px;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div id="root"></div>

   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
   ```