# Передать данные от ребёнка к ребёнку

Tags: reactjs, react-hook

Как передать данные от родителя к ребёнку, когда данные от другого ребёнка к родителю были получены?

а то null передаёт

`<ButtonsSaveComponent settings={{difficulty, operators}}/>`

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import DifficultyComponent from "../components/SettingsPagesComponents/DifficultyComponent";
import OperatorsCheckBoxesComponent from "../components/SettingsPagesComponents/OperatorsCheckBoxesComponent";
import ButtonsSaveComponent from "../components/SettingsPagesComponents/ButtonsSaveComponent";

const SettingsTest = () => {

    const [difficulty, setDifficulty] = useState(0);
    const [operators, setOperators] = useState({"plus": true, "minus": true, "multiply": true, "divide": true});

    

    const updateDataDifficulty = (data) => {
        setDifficulty(data);
    }

    const updateDataOperators = (data) => {
        setOperators(data);
    }

    return (
        <div>

            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                        <h1>Настройки игры</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h1>{difficulty}</h1>
                <DifficultyComponent updateDataDifficulty={updateDataDifficulty}/>
                <OperatorsCheckBoxesComponent updateDataOperators={updateDataOperators}/>
                <ButtonsSaveComponent settings={{difficulty, operators}}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default SettingsTest;
```

ButtonsSaveComponent. Здесь я хочу получать данные от родителя, которому уже пришли другие данные от детей. Но сюда они приходят дефолтные, хотя если смотреть в родителе, то они изменились

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

const ButtonsSaveComponent = ( {settings} ) => {

    const [difficulty, setDifficulty] = useState();
    const [operators, setOperators] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        setDifficulty(settings.difficulty);
        setOperators(settings.operators);
    }, []);

    return (
};

export default ButtonsSaveComponent;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `useState()` - положите туда начальное значение например `null` и в `ButtonsSaveComponent` пропишите начальные данные, если на вход придут `null`
2. `updateDataDifficulty`  бесполезен, если вы никак не обрабатываете входящий `data`, можете сразу передавать в дочерний элемент `setDifficulty`

Comment: я везде от двух компонентов отправляю данные в родительский. не понимаю одно, зачем ложить null?

Comment: @Merka Чтобы было начальное значение перед тем как придут значения из дочерних

Comment: Хочу ещё узнать. Вот от ребёнка к родителю я получаю спокойно, но когда передаю от ребёнка уже в ребёнка через родителя, там дефолтны значения только. Как передать их изменённые так скажем?

Comment: @Merka Посмотрите мой ответ на другой вопрос, там есть то что вам надо: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1429509/385375

Comment: "можете сразу передавать в дочерний элемент setDifficulty" тоже не пойму. можете на моем коде показать?

Comment: @Merka `updateDataDifficulty={setDifficulty}` ну или просто `setDifficulty={setDifficulty}`

Comment: Я вот щас посмотрел тот ваш ответ. Мне щас надо context вместо useState? везде

Comment: @Merka На ваш выбор. Можно и через контекст, можно и напрямую через родителя, если дочерние компоненты близко друг к другу расположены

Comment: Ну вот я щас так и пытался. К родителю идеально пришли, а от родителя дефолтные. изменил код, выше смотрите елси что

Comment: @Merka Я не могу так сказать, что именно пошло не так. Может вы в самих компонентах не правильно обновляете, может быть ещё другие причины. Здесь есть [интсрукция](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12004/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%a4%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-stack-snippet-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-react-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-jsx) как выложить минимальный воспроизводимый код React. Уберите всё лишнее в коде и оставьте только моменты передачи и обновления данных

Comment: Добавил. Посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: @Merka В массив зависимостей положите `settings.difficulty` и `settings.operators`, чтобы он отрабатывал, каждый раз при изменении значений этих переменных

Comment: Всё! спасибо огромное)

Comment: Я вот только сегодня начал тыкать реакт. Это правильно что я всё так разделяю? или лучше бы в одном всё сделал одну страницу

Comment: @Merka Чем меньше компонента тем лучше, прямо как с функциями. Если вопрос в целом про архитектуру, то это очень часто субъетивное мнение бывает. Есть, конечно, в самой документации общие рекомендации, которые очень полезны, но всё остальное редко бывает чем-то объективным. Кому что кажется удобнее то и творит)